# obtener valores de un select2 para usarlos en un modelo

Tags: jquery, django, select2, django-templates

Estoy tratando de obtener los datos de un select con la herramienta select2, todo se muestra correctamente, pero cuando quiero usar esos datos seleccionados, no hay forma de acceder a ellos desde el view.py

Aquí mi view.py, no me da ningún problema al renderizar, pero no sé como acceder desde aquí a los datos seleccionados con `cleaned_data` o algún metodo similar

```
def RecepVentaView(request):
    clienten=Cliente.objects.all()
    DispMoto=Motocicleta.objects.filter(Disp_M="Disponible")
    idrep=Cargo.objects.get(NombreCargo="Repartidor").id
    DispRep=Trabajador.objects.filter(Disp_T="Disponible", Cargo=idrep)
    Titulo = "¿Nuevo Pedido?"
    form = RecepVentaModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect('npedido')
    else:
        form = RecepVentaModelForm()
    context = {
        "titulo": Titulo,
        "form": form,
        "dispmoto": DispMoto,
        "disprep": DispRep,
        "clienten": clienten,
    }
    return render(request, "nrecepventa.html", context)
```

Aquí mi template que funciona bien pero no registra ningún dato de select2

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    
{% block head %}Nuevo Pedido{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-5">
            <a href="{% url 'ncliente' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Registrar Nuevo Cliente</a>
            <br><br>
                <select class="form-control" name="buscarc" id="buscarc">
                    <option value="0">Elegir cliente</option>
                    {% for item in clienten %}
                        <option value="{{ item.id }}">{{item.Nombre_Cl}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            <br><br>
            <form>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <br>
            </form>
            <p></p>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Elegir menú" onclick=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buscarc').select2({
            allowClear:true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el valor desde request.POST, este es un diccionario que contiene todos los valores enviados mediante método POST sin haber sido procesados o limpiados.

En este caso deberías de poder acceder al valor del select de esta manera:

```
buscarc = request.POST.get("buscarc")
if buscarc:
    print("Se recibio el valor")
```

Si intentas obtener el valor desde form.cleaned_data no podrás obtener el valor si no agregas el campo a tu formulario.

Comment: Holaaaaa, tienes toda la razón, te agradezco, solo quiero complementarte que los valores que devuelve son los id de la opción elegida por lo tanto hay que usar el metodo get con los modelos nativos para obtener elementos para trabajar, por si a alguien le sirve. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo OwO

Comment: Si disculpa, olvide mencionar esa parte, si te sirvio la respuesta la puedes marcar como aceptada para futuras referencias.